# Rare usage of perfect tenses ("to have been" and "to have done") by Daniel Defoe

Tags: grammar, usage, present-perfect, future-perfect

Reading "The Further Adventures of Robinson Crusoe" by Daniel Defoe, I run into the following excerpt:

> I say, after all this, any one would have thought that the native propensity to rambling which I gave an account of in *my first setting out in the world* **to have been so predominant** in my thoughts, should be worn out, and I might, at sixty one years of age, have been a little inclined to stay at home, and **have done venturing life and fortune any more**.

I suppose I have understood the sense of the quote above completely. However, I have no idea what grammar rules are behind it.

I have several questions:

1) If one replaces the first phrase in bold (**to have been so predominant**) with "**which was so predominant**", will the sense be the same?

2) Does the second phrase in bold (**have done venturing life and fortune any more**) mean "**would not venture life and fortune any more**"? Specifically, I do not grasp, why he uses no negation before "any more"? Would it be correct to replace "any more" with "no longer"?

3) What grammar rules describe the usages above?

UPDATE:

4) The phrase "*my first setting out in the world*" isn't clear too. Does "a setting out" mean "a narration" here? And if so, why *in the world* instead of *to the world*? Or maybe "a setting out" is "a beginning (of a journey)"?

Comment: I don't understand the grammar of the first part of the sentence either. _Have done_ = _have finished with_.

Comment: I'm not gonna criticize Defoe, so I suppose *... propensity to rambling which I **gave an account of** ...to have been so predominant in my thoughts* must have been okay for him and his contemporaries. But replacing that highlighted verb phrase with ***showed, demonstrated, established,...*** gives a construction that makes sense to my modern ear. I'd just use the simple infinitive *to **be** so predominant*, but I guess Present Perfect ***have been*** "kinda" makes sense there (or at least, it did to Defoe! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I think this part: "gave an account ... to be so predominant..." should be separated out, so the structure left is "... anyone would have thought the native propensity to rambling should be worn out, and..."
So, "gave an account to be so predominant" doesn't work in modern English, but maybe it did then. At any rate, I can't assemble the whole otherwise.

2) "... I might have been ... inclined... and might have done venturing..."
 Here, 'have done' has a negative sense, usually expressed in modern English as 'have done with', or 'be finished with'.

I would say that his native propensity to rambling was not worn out, but was transferred entire to his writing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have added the 4th question. Take a look, please.

Comment: From the context, it  must mean his first narration. Usually, "setting out" would mean the start of a journey, but it also can mean "exposition", as you  have noted.